# How to use the new Android Constraint Layout to reduce View hierarchy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-constraintlayout

Do you have any idea on how to use the new Constraint Layout that was recently announced at this year's Google I/O?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can go to an existing layout resource file, open the visual editor and right-click on a RelativeLayout (for example) and click the option to convert to a constraint layout.

You also have to add the Gradle dependency in build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
```

Comment: If any one is viewing this answer on 8th November,2016 and onwards, please use 
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3' 
Infect, the best way to solve this problem is shown in this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39631045/1362418

Comment: This new layout, should we still provide landscape mode xml for this? Or it will automatically re flow the components base on that rope line.

Comment: From android studio 2.3 onwards, you can use `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` .

Comment: It is mentioned here https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview .

Answer (score 17):

From [Docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor)

*If you're updating an existing project, proceed as follows:*

Ensure you have the latest Android Support Repository (**version 32 or higher**): *// This was the part that was missing for me*

**Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
Click the SDK Tools tab.
Select Android Support Repository, then click OK.**

**Add the updated Constraint Layout library as a dependency** in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
}
```

In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

To add a new constraint layout to your project:

- Right-click on your module's layout directory, then click New > XML > Layout XML.
  Enter a name for the layout and enter "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" for the Root Tag.
  Click Finish.

To convert an existing layout to a constraint layout:

- Open your existing layout in Android Studio and select the Design tab at the bottom of the editor window.
  In the Component Tree window, right-click the layout and click Convert  to ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 5):

Go though this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) from **Google CodeLabs**. You will have basic idea of **Constraint Layout** and how to use different constraints like `Manual Constraint`, `Auto Connect` & `Inference`.

Also there is `UI Builder` & `Inspector` which will help us to build faster UI.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many version, but i couldn't solve the issue! Finally i let Android Studio to solve this issue.

In the XML file, Beside error message you can see this option! Click on that to import reccomonded version

[image: using version 1.0.0-alpha2 of the constraint library which is obsolete]

or you can press alt+enter placing your cursor on error line

I got constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8, when i pressed alt+enter

> compile
>   'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and I don't get the Options icon next to the error message.

Answer (score 2):

add dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

And create new layout xml file **-->** goto design tab **-->** right click your root layout and select last option **convert LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout**

**See Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should add google maven repository in module level gradle file(**important part**)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

then add this line in dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding the performance benefits of ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) describes the expense of a traditional layout hierarchy. It gives an example of this layout built with nested layouts

[image: Example view]

and claims that

> ConstraintLayout performs about 40% better in the measure/layout phase than RelativeLayout

This [Codelab project](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html) shows how to use the ConstaintLayout to reduce View hierarchy and flatten above-mentioned layout.

[image: Codelab Project]

Answer (score 0):

**1)** To design a new layout using ConstraintLayout, include the dependency in the app.gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
```

Note: For each view in the layout, you have to include following attributes, else the views are shown at (0,0).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ....>

        <View
           android:id="@+id/top_view"
           .../>

        <View
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_view"
        ..../>

       <View
           android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
           .../>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2)** To convert an existing layout file to a constraint layout:

Open your existing layout in Android Studio and select the Design tab at the bottom of the editor window. In the Component Tree window, right-click the root layout and click Convert to ConstraintLayout. Then include the up defined attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependencies in the file `build.gradle`.

Use compile `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google released the official version 1.0 **ConstraintLayout**

now import the non beta version

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
```

Check here info
http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout10isnowavailable